# Why does my ASP.NET log-in page not route to the index page after logging in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-6.0

After I log-in, it not route to index page.

I do log-in page, learning by myself in Youtube and I got problem about log-in page.

The process should be, after I log-in, if log-in passed, it should be auto route to Index page but after I log-in, it applied to relog-in again. not go to Index page.

login.cshtml

```
@page
@model OT6.Pages.Account.LoginModel
@{
}

<div class="container border" style="padding:20px">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Credential.UserName"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="text" asp-for="Credential.UserName" />
               
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
               
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Credential.UserName"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Credential.Password"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="password" asp-for="Credential.Password" />
                
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Credential.Password"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="login" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

login.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

namespace OT6.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Credential Credential { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();

            //verify the credential

            if (Credential.UserName == "admin" && Credential.Password == "password")
            {
                //Creating the security context
                List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin@OT2.com")


                };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyCookieAuth");
                ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieAuth", claimsPrincipal);

                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme );

                AuthenticationProperties propertied = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true
                };

                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
            return Page();
        }

    }
    public class Credential
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public String UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public String Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

index.xshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace OT6.Pages
{
    [Authorize]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you set a breakpoint at `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();` ? What's the result of the `ModelState.IsValid` ?

Comment: Besides, what's  the result of `if (Credential.UserName == "admin" && Credential.Password == "password")` ?